# SQL WHERE Clause Optimization

Tags: sql, optimization

Suppose I have the following three types:

- Type1
- Type2
- Type3

From an optimization standpoint (ignoring maintainabilty; I know that the first option is less likely to break if a new type is added); would it be more efficient to write my where clause like this:

```
WHERE p.TypeId IN (Type1, Type2)
```

or

```
WHERE p.TypeId <> Type3
```

Comment: can `p.typeid` be NULL ?

Comment: This is an interesting question from a theoretical standpoint but I can't help but wonder if it's worth worrying about...

Comment: The difference between these would likely be so minor that you would never notice in a real world application.  As a note, though, you should mention the database and try running variants on your system with your data.

Comment: The answer, I think, would be "it depends". Depends on the table size, presence of an index, column cardinality and value distribution, whether the distribution statistics are collected etc. In other words, you won't know until you test.

Comment: Or use a table & JOIN across an index

Comment: This may be better over on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is essentially: Which of these two predicates are SARGable. That is a legitimate question. This can be a difference of orders of magnitude.

Comment: My TLAR (That Looks About Right) rule is that  `IN (..)` ends up `OR`ing each value in parentheses.  So `TypeID` indexing or not for large `IN` groups, I'd default to  `<>` over `IN`. If performance REALLY matters, then what @mustaccio said.

Comment: @radarbob -- "_IN (..) ends up ORing each value in parentheses_" -- that's pure speculation.

Comment: @mustaccio, tell it to Microsoft; this is precisely what I was taught in the O-fishal SQL course. So, when it comes to Oracle, Sybase, etc. it could be hypothesis, but it is not speculation.

Comment: @radarbob - you said it was _your_ rule, didn't you? Does your experience support what Microsoft supposedly taught you?

Answer (score 0):

Your second option:

```
WHERE p.TypeId <> Type3
```

Will be more efficient to write, as it uses fewer characters, unless you're on an iPad in which case it's quite slow to get to the < and > chars!

In terms of execution it'll also be faster to execute. Clearly it has less work to do as only a single comparison is required, so whichever way you optimise it <> is going to be faster than IN with two elements.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on how indexes are configured and what data is in the tables, but for a simple test case, they can be demonstrated to create identical query plans in SQL Server 2005.

The following code, run on a SQL Server 2005 instance, produced identical query plans for the OR, IN, and inequality versions of the queries. Each query produced the same number of records. The first set of queries uses a 3-value equal distribution. The second set of queries uses a 10-value equal distribution.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (TestID int, TestTypeID int);

WITH TallyTable AS
(
    SELECT
    TOP 10000
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Tally
    FROM            sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN      sys.objects s2
), InsertList AS
(
    SELECT
        Tally AS TestID,
        Tally % 3 AS TestTypeID
    FROM    TallyTable
)
INSERT INTO #Test
    (
        TestID,
        TestTypeID
    )
SELECT
    TestID,
    TestTypeID
FROM        InsertList;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID = 0
OR          TestTypeID = 2;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID IN (0,2);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID <> 1;

CREATE INDEX TestIndex ON #Test (TestTypeID);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID = 0
OR          TestTypeID = 2;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID IN (0,2);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID <> 1;

DROP INDEX TestIndex ON #Test;

TRUNCATE TABLE #Test;

WITH TallyTable AS
(
    SELECT
    TOP 10000
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Tally
    FROM            sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN      sys.objects s2
), InsertList AS
(
    SELECT
        Tally AS TestID,
        Tally % 10 AS TestTypeID
    FROM    TallyTable
)
INSERT INTO #Test
    (
        TestID,
        TestTypeID
    )
SELECT
    TestID,
    TestTypeID
FROM        InsertList;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID = 0
OR          TestTypeID = 2
OR          TestTypeID = 3
OR          TestTypeID = 4
OR          TestTypeID = 5
OR          TestTypeID = 6
OR          TestTypeID = 7
OR          TestTypeID = 8
OR          TestTypeID = 9;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID IN (0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID <> 1;

CREATE INDEX TestIndex ON #Test (TestTypeID);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID = 0
OR          TestTypeID = 2
OR          TestTypeID = 3
OR          TestTypeID = 4
OR          TestTypeID = 5
OR          TestTypeID = 6
OR          TestTypeID = 7
OR          TestTypeID = 8
OR          TestTypeID = 9;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID IN (0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID <> 1;

DROP TABLE #Test;
```

This set uses a 3-value unequal distribution and also results in the same query plans.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test (TestID int, TestTypeID int);

WITH TallyTable AS
(
    SELECT
    TOP 10000
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Tally
    FROM            sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN      sys.objects s2
), InsertList AS
(
    SELECT
        Tally AS TestID,
        CASE
            WHEN Tally % 1000 = 0 THEN 2
            WHEN Tally % 100 = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS TestTypeID
    FROM    TallyTable
)
INSERT INTO #Test
    (
        TestID,
        TestTypeID
    )
SELECT
    TestID,
    TestTypeID
FROM        InsertList;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID = 0
OR          TestTypeID = 2;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID IN (0,2);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID <> 1;

CREATE INDEX TestIndex ON #Test (TestTypeID);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID = 0
OR          TestTypeID = 2;

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID IN (0,2);

SELECT
    TestTypeID
FROM        #Test
WHERE       TestTypeID <> 1;

DROP TABLE #Test;
```